# change color of the badge - condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, badge

I am a beginner at React. I would like to change the color of the badge in dependency to the number of registered students. Something like on the picture. If the item.registeredCount (number of registered students) = (item.capacity - 1) then the color will be red (for example 1/2, 4/5, 10/11, etc) else the color of the badge will be green because the capacity is not half full. In case when the item.capacity = 1, the color of the badge will be green.

My code:

```
<Col className="text-center">
   <div>
      <Badge 
          bg="danger">{item.registeredCount}  /  {item.capacity}
      </Badge>
   </div>
</Col>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can use the ternary operator ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)) to choose your badge's color.

```
<Badge bg={(item.registeredCount === item.capacity - 1) ? "green" : "danger"}>{item.registeredCount}  /  {item.capacity}
</Badge>
```